# Get PowerShell Script to Run SharePoint Commands on Azure

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, sharepoint

I have a PowerShell script that is supposed to run on SharePoint. I've been trying to work on the code with C# on Visual Studio 2019. I've tried few different ways but none of them worked. Ultimately I want these commands to run on the bot deployed on Azure.

I have done `Install-Module SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline` on the PowerShell and `Install-Package SharePointPnPCoreOnline -Version 3.12.1908` through PM on Visual Studio. 
My script worked fine on PowerShell but it did not work when I tried to invoke the script with C#. 
I kept getting this error - `System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException: 'The term 'Connect-PnPOnline'` is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

I have found some solutions that use `RunspaceConfiguration` from `System.Management.Automation.Runspaces`. But seems like `RunspaceConfiguration` is removed from the namespace as I cannot find it.

I have tried to invoke the script by doing

`PowerShellInstance.AddScript(script)` or `PowerShellInstance.AddCommand("Connect-PnPOnline").AddParameter()...` But both didn't work.

Both `PowerShellInst.Invoke()` and `pipeline.Invoke()` returned the error that `Connect-Online` is not recognized. And I got this error only on Visual Studio instead of PowerShell.

This code has the error at `pipeline.Invoke()` that `Connect-PnPOnline` is not recognized
1st example

```cs
{
    string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\xxx\xxx\oo.ps1");

    Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
    runspace.Open();
    Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
    pipeline.Commands.AddScript(text);

    Collection<PSObject> PSOutput = pipeline.Invoke();
    foreach (PSObject obj in PSOutput)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(obj.BaseObject.ToString());
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Done");

    runspace.Close();
}
```

This code has the error at `PowerShellInst.Invoke()` that `Connect-PnPOnline` is not recognized
2nd example

```cs
using (PowerShell PowerShellInst = PowerShell.Create())
{
    PowerShellInst.AddCommand("Connect-PnPOnline")
                    .AddParameter("site", "https://xxxxx.sharepoint.com/xxxxx").AddParameter("url", "site").AddParameter("UseWebLogin", "xxx")
                    .AddParameter("-Credentials", "xxxxx");
    Collection<PSObject> PSOutput = PowerShellInst.Invoke();
    foreach (PSObject obj in PSOutput)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Read context of the Script: " + obj.BaseObject.ToString());
    }
}
```

Here is my sample script.

```
$site="https://xxxxx.sharepoint.com/xxxxx"

Connect-PnPOnline -url $site -UseWebLogin xxx -Credentials $xxxx

New-PnPWeb -Template "{xxxxxx}#ooo_projecttemplate" -Title $projecttitle -Url $projectnumber -Locale "777" -Description $theDescription -BreakInheritance

New-PnPGroup -Title $Title -owner $ID
```

Seems the issue is that SharePoint commands cannot be recognized when I try to execute my script with C# on Visual Studio. Does anyone have similar problems or any idea about how to solve this?

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow below official guideline to import module.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-design-pnp-provisioning#upload-the-pnp-powershell-module-for-your-azure-function

To create PowerShell script function, check [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/ae96c03e-8194-428c-9c31-d0b093db628a/pnp-script-on-azure?forum=appsforsharepoint).

My test demo(Get-PnPWeb|select Title, below screenshot not update to latest script):
[image]