# How do I run PnP Script on Azure Function App

Tags: azure, powershell, sharepoint

I am trying to get a user to run a powershell script through an Azure function. This script is supposed to create a site on SharePoint with some info provided by users.

I created an Azure Function App to run some PowerShell scripts. When I tried to run my code, it returned an error `http 502` at `Connect-PnPOnline`
If I remove `Connect-PnPOnline`, I get a 200 response. So I am sure that it has to do with `Connect-PnPOnline` in my script.

I followed the post by @Lee_MSFT  [Get PowerShell Script to Run SharePoint Commands on Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57614980/get-powershell-script-to-run-sharepoint-commands-on-azure)
and able to import modules.

```
using namespace System.Net

param (
    [string]$projectnumber,
    [string]$projectname
)

$site = "https://xxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/projects"

$projectsite = -join($site, "/", $projectnumber)
$projecttitle = -join($projectnumber, " ", $projectname)

Connect-PnPOnline -url $site 
...
```

I got 500 from `Connect-PnPOnline -url $site` and a 502 from `Connect-PnPOnline -url $site -UseWebLogin`

Anyone know that why I have 5xx errors while using `Connect-PnPOnline`?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't think you can use an interactive way to connect in azure function. If your account is MFA-enabled, you may need to use an AD app to do that, like `Connect-PnPOnline -AppId '<id>' -AppSecret '<secret>' -AADDomain 'contoso.onmicrosoft.com'`. If your account is not MFA-enabled, I think the way provided by Lee_MSFT will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have upload the PnP PowerShell module for your Azure Function, then use the PowerShell below to connect the SharePoint.

```
$siteURL = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/projects"    
$userId = "abc@tenant.onmicrosoft.com"    
$plainText= "*****"  
$pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString $plainText -AsPlainText -Force    
$creds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($userId,$pwd)  
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteURL -Credentials $creds
```

Or use this:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -AppId $env:SPO_AppId -AppSecret $env:SPO_AppSecret -Url "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/projects"
```

**SPO_AppId** - Set the value to the Client ID you copied in the first step when you created your app on your tenant.

**SPO_AppSecret** - Set the value to the Client Secret that you copied in the first step when you created your app on your tenant.

I suggest you check the steps in the article below.

[Azure Functions For SharePoint Operations Using PnP PowerShell](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/azure-functions-for-sharepoint-operations-using-pnp-powershell/)